# Cross-Validation wihout using sklearn only numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do the hyperparameter search for a polynomial regression and I wanna know if it's possible to do it with numpy only without scikit-learn (sklearn and others).
How can i do it ? Can you show an exemple ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do it. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Where is aminimal example you are working on? Consider looking at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Onyambu I'm doing basic machine learning without using third-party libraries just with basic python and a little bit numpy. Now I'm thinking about cross-validation and found the best N degree. Any example I see online they use sklearn or others. I don't have any minimal code to show, I'm just trying to find out if numpy can do the job and if someone can show me an example or tutorial that would be welcome.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can do it by simple hyperparameter search for polynomial regression using NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
X = 2 * np.random.rand(100, 1)
y = 4 + 3 * X + np.random.randn(100, 1)

# Function to calculate mean squared error for polynomial regression
def calculate_mse(X, y, coeffs):
    y_pred = np.polyval(coeffs, X)
    return np.mean((y_pred - y) ** 2)

best_degree = None
best_coeffs = None
best_mse = float('inf')

for degree in range(1, 10):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(X.flatten(), y.flatten(), degree)
    mse = calculate_mse(X, y, coeffs)

    if mse < best_mse:
        best_degree = degree
        best_coeffs = coeffs
        best_mse = mse

print(f"Best polynomial degree: {best_degree}")
print(f"Best polynomial coefficients: {best_coeffs}")
print(f"Best Mean Squared Error: {best_mse}")
```

However, i will suggest that prefer scikit-learn for hyperparameter search and model evaluation

Comment: How is this `cross-validation`? Cross validation has to evaluate the model on **unseen data**. Where is the *unseen data* in your case? Either K-fold or LOOCV